# Looping through directories in Bash

Tags: bash, scripting, loops

I require the script to `cd` to a directory, then delete all but a few files in sub-directories—but leave the folders alone.  Would it help to use `switch`/`case`s for each file I need to preserve?

Ideally, I think it should keep searching for further sub-dirs, instead of me having nested loops which only search down two levels.

Another problem is that it skips folders with spaces (though this isn’t an issue with the volumes that the script will run, for now).

Here’s my code:

```sh
for i in /Users/YourName/Desktop/Test/* ; do
  if [ -d "$i" ]; then
    cd $i

    for j in "$i"/* ; do
      if [ -d "$j" ]; then
        cd $j

        for k in $(ls *); do
          if [ ! $k == "watch.log" ]; then
            echo $k
            rm -rf $k
          fi
        done

      fi
    done

  fi
done
```

Comment: don't guess at what is failing. make sure that it is indeed the `cd` that is wrong, we can't guess.

Comment: with rm -rf you are not only removing files, but also the (sub-) directories. but reading your question and comparing it to the included source-code, i am not really sure what you would like to do anyway ...

Comment: Sorry Mat.  I accidentally hit return while writing this post, which had a draft to an old problem now resolved.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Herald.  Yeah, I forgot about the rm -r trigger.  I will definitely need to rewrite script and post then.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about this?

```sh
$ find /Users/YourName/Desktop/Test -type f -maxdepth 2 -not -name watch.log -delete
```

### Explanation

- `-type`: look for files only
- `-maxdepth`: go down two levels at most
- `-not -name` (combo): exclude `watch.log` from the search
- `-delete`: deletes files

### Recommendation

Try out the above command without the `-delete` flag first. That will print out a list of files that would have been deleted.

Once you’re happy with the list, add `-delete` back to the command.

Comment: This works great!  My only concern, it also picks up .files which could be avoided, but I'm guessing this is simple to implement.  Many thanks - you've turned my script into one line!  I really need to learn these commands.

Answer (score 32):

You should use `find` :

```
for i in $(find . -type d)
do
    do_stuff "$i"
done
```

If you really have a lot of directories, you can pipe the output of find into a `while read` loop, but it makes coding harder as the loop is in another process.

About spaces, be sure to quote the variable containing the directory name. That should allow you to handle directories with spaces in their names fine.

Comment: Thank you.  I really need to get more familiar with find.

Comment: This will break if directories have whitespace characters in their name.

Comment: For loops over find are considered fragile. For more info refer https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2044

Answer (score 2):

Using find? You can use several parameters, including depth, file age (as in stat), perms etc...

```
find . -maxdepth 2
```

Comment: Your entire script can be performed with a single line. Look at the `-maxdepth`, `-mindepth`, `-name`, and `-exec` options of find. If I read your intent correctly it should be something like: `find /Users/YourName/Desktop/Test -mindepth 2 -name "watch.log" -exec rm -rf {} \; -prune`